# Simple specific classes design

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am new to c#, and rather new to design-patterns. I want to create a simple and a most elegant solution for loading and validating a xml file and later on extracting its fields.
I've started with a generic `IData` interface, that gets implemented by a `XmlFileData` class, but I feel that there is much more to be improved upon, but I lack the knowledge to do it (from design, to naming variables and methods and so on).

So please, have no mercy !!

```
public interface IData
{
     String GetDataString();
}

class XMLValidator
    {
        private StringBuilder verificationErrorsList = new StringBuilder();
        public string ValidationSchema { get; set; }
        public String ValidationErrors
        {
            get { return verificationErrorsList.ToString(); }
        }
        public bool HasErrors
        {
            get {return (verificationErrorsList.Length > 0);}
        }

        public void Validate(IData xmlData)
        {
            try
            {
                XmlWriterSettings ws = new XmlWriterSettings();
                ws.Indent = true;

                XmlReaderSettings rs = new XmlReaderSettings();
                rs.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
                rs.ValidationEventHandler += new System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventHandler(rs_ValidationEventHandler);
                rs.Schemas.Add(null, ValidationSchema);
                rs.CloseInput = true;

                rs.ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings |  XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessIdentityConstraints |
                               XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema |  XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;

                StringReader r = new StringReader(xmlData.GetDataString());
                using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(r, rs))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        while (reader.Read()) { }
                    }
                    catch (XmlException e)
                    {
                        verificationErrorsList.Append(e.Message);
                        verificationErrorsList.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (XmlSchemaValidationException e)
            {
                verificationErrorsList.Append(e.Message + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
        void rs_ValidationEventHandler(object sender, System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error || e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
            {
                verificationErrorsList.Append(e.Message + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
        IData data = new XmlFileData(basepathXML + fileNameXML);
        XMLValidator validator = new XMLValidator();
        validator.ValidationSchema = basepathXML + fileNameXSD;
        validator.Validate(data);
        if (validator.HasErrors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(validator.ValidationErrors);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
        }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A few things:

1. `IData` is not a particularly good name for the interface as it represents a source of data rather than the data itself. Therefor `IDataSource` seems more appropriate.
2. The interface is a bit ambiguous - which method am I supposed to use `GetDataStream` or `GetDataString`? Why use one or the other? Could I call both multiple times and interchangeably?

   As of now it doesn't really provide enough value to warrant it's existence. You'd be better of having `XmlValidator` accept a [`TextReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and let the calling code deal with how to wrap it around the source.
3. Consider passing the `ValidationSchema` as part of the constructor for the `XmlValidator` - it's an integral part of its validation logic.
4. In the validator when the reader throws an exception because there was a problem reading from the stream for example then you catch those as validation errors which I'd consider technically wrong. Your validator should catch validation errors - i.e. anything that has to do with invalid XML. Everything else should not be of its concern. So don't catch `Exception` - be more specific.

Comment: 2. i wanted to generalize the xml data file, for the sake of completeness, maybe some day the data source might be a url, a network stream, an encripted file? Regarding those to methods.. The GetDataStream() method is has no use right now .. 1,3 done. 4. Ok.. So you say I should only catch validation exceptions in the validator.. so does my updated code meet that point?

Comment: @A.K: Re 2) Sure but your interface should hide that. You don't want a call for every possible type of source on your interface. It should have a generic method which supplies data regardless of the source. `TextReader` is not an interface but a generic enough abstract base class which should serve the purpose well.

Answer (score 10):

There is a lot that can be simplified. `AppendLine()` instead of `Append()` with `Environment.NewLine`, object initializer syntax, etc.

`ws = new XmlWriterSettings` is never used.

Also, `StringReader` is also an `IDisposable` resource and should therefore be wrapped in `using`.

I've also put the very short validation event handler method inline with a lambda.

```
public interface IData
{
    Stream GetDataStream();

    string GetDataString();
}

internal class XmlValidator
{
    private readonly StringBuilder verificationErrorsList = new StringBuilder();

    public string ValidationSchema
    {
        get;

        set;
    }

    public string ValidationErrors
    {
        get
        {
            return this.verificationErrorsList.ToString();
        }
    }

    public bool HasErrors
    {
        get
        {
            return this.verificationErrorsList.Length > 0;
        }
    }

    public void Validate(IData xmlData)
    {
        try
        {
            ////var ws = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true };
            var rs = new XmlReaderSettings
            {
                ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema,
                CloseInput = true,
                ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings
                    | XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessIdentityConstraints
                    | XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema
                    | XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation
            };

            rs.ValidationEventHandler += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error || e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
                {
                    this.verificationErrorsList.AppendLine(e.Message);
                }
            };
            rs.Schemas.Add(null, this.ValidationSchema);
            using (var r = new StringReader(xmlData.GetDataString()))
            using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(r, rs))
            {
                try
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    this.verificationErrorsList.AppendLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.verificationErrorsList.AppendLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```